# Where do I get a product key and ISO for Windows 8 Boot Camp?

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows

(Please note that this is a hypothetical question as I do not yet own the computer mentioned in this post, but will be getting it next year for school)

Next year, I am going to buy a MacBook Pro Retina for school. The IST course I will be taking requires Windows for Android development. Where would I download the ISO for installing Windows 8, and where would I buy a product key? I'd like the Pro version too because I want to use remote desktop from my iPad when necessary (I already know how to do this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has a Student store that sells [Windows 8](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/Windows-8.1-Pro-for-Students/productID.288769600), downloadable, with key for $69. Presumably from your post, you would qualify for academic pricing.

[image]

Comment: note that is is an upgrade and this will not work for the OP- the OP needs a non upgrade version witch I think is System Builder which MS hides

Comment: But you can do a clean install from the upgrade disk. http://lifehacker.com/5984278/